# creating a class that holds 3 separate views

Tags: android, view

Basically I want one class to hold 3 separate `Views` on one screen.

I would like the top **half** of the screen to display a panoramic `View` (which I have defined in Panorama.java), and the bottom half will be split in half vertically and have 2 separate `Views` on them. On the left I would have my map class(CampusMap.java) and on the right I would have my other `Activity` (CampusTour.java).

Is this possible? If so, how would I implement it?

Comment: yes, but what are you wanting from us?

Comment: I'm wondering how I would go about implementing it............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments my friend...the answer you seek is Fragments...

They are basically modular code blocks that consist of an XML file married to Java code.  They can be populated inside of a single container view, have work done to them via the container or via their own code, and can be removed and added at run time

Answer (score 2):

[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) may be what you are looking for.

You can have multiple fragments on the same screen at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

you can only run one activity at a time. You probably looking to implement three `views` in a single layout.

Comment: Fragments can actually do something similar to what he is saying.

Comment: I am yet to play with fragments. Cool. +1
though looks like he just need views in this case.

Comment: Takes a little while to get used to, after you have been using `Activities` for so long. But it is very powerful once you get a good grasp on it. However, it is a little painful to work with `Fragments` using the support library. =(